# Dropdown identification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dropdown options:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li hidden class="inicio"><a href "#">Inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="Drop1">OPTION 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="bd-ric"><a href="#">Option 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 1.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="Drop2">OPTION 2<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="bd-ric"><a href="#">Option 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 2.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When i tried to create the Javascript to toggle it, they both opened:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
})
```

Should I create a function and invoke it on the html or can I call the toggle event for a specific id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's `next` method](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```js
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li hidden class="inicio"><a href "#">Inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="Drop1">OPTION 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="bd-ric"><a href="#">Option 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 1.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="Drop2">OPTION 2<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="bd-ric"><a href="#">Option 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 2.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @TiagoMatos não há de quê :)